# Download Multiple Files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

```
%= link_to "Bulk Download" ,download_tickets_path({:id=>@ticket.id})%>
    <%end%>
```

In controller:

```
def download
@ticket.ticket_files.each do |ticket_file|
send_file ticket_file.file.path
end
end
```

but only downloading single file

Comment: What is the count of `@ticket.ticket_files`?

Comment: No certain count .. it could me multiple like 1 or 2 or 10 ..

Comment: So, check whether the count is 1 before downloading.

Comment: <%= @ticket.ticket_files.count %> it showing no of files present, not one